# Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource when sending mail

Tags: java, netbeans, smtp

I'm trying to send Mail using SMTP on NetBeans when I get the error message:

> run: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> javax/activation/DataSource   at
> SendMail.createMessage(SendMail.java:45)  at
> SendMail.main(SendMail.java:59) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource     at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> ... 2 more
> C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:111:
> The following error occurred while executing this line:
> C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:68:
> Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

How do I need to fix it?

(I use Apache NetBeans IDE 12.0;
Java: 15; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 15+36-156)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For classes such as `javax.activation.DataSource` you need the JAR file for the JavaBeans Activation Framework.

You can download the JAR from Maven Central [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation/1.1.1) - click on the `jar` link there.

If you are using a dependency management tool such as Maven, Gradle, etc. then use the related configuration (also available in that same page). Using a dependency management tool is **strongly recommended** over just downloading JAR files one-by-one.

---

You should also consider replacing your `javax` imports with `jakarta` imports, since that is now [where these packages are maintained](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee), going forward.

If you do that, then you need to use the Jakarta Activation API, available [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.activation/jakarta.activation-api). For example:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And if you do that, you should also replace JavaMail classes too - for example, you can replace this:

```java
import javax.mail.Message;
```

with this:

```java
import jakarta.mail.Message;
```

And use a [Jakarta Mail](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/jakarta.mail) resource, for example:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I solved the problem, thank you!

Comment: The link to Maven points to old Javax Activation. The new link seems to be https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.activation/jakarta.activation

Comment: Thank you for your comment @JustAMartin. The Jakarta Activation link in the answer points to where the latest versions are maintained in Maven (currently `2.1.0`). The link in your comment only includes Jakarta versions up to `2.0.1` - it still references `com.sun.activation` in the URL - I think that was just a transitional Maven location for the libraries. Now, everything is located under `jakarta.activation`. At least, that is my understanding - I could be wrong.

Comment: Try the link in your text "You can download the JAR from Maven Central here" - when clicking on "here" it leads to old version 1.1.1 for some reason.

Comment: Yes - that is deliberate, because the question was using `javax` libraries. So that link is for the missing `javax` activation JAR, to directly answer the question. But then I added a follow-up recommendation for using `jakarta` libraries - and I provided the `jakarta` link for the Activation framework, My Jakarta link in the answer is more up-to-date than your Jakarta link in the comment. Am I missing something here? If so, my apologies. @JustAMartin

Answer (score 0):

When running with the spring parent, it was the easiest for me to set a consistent version with this maven property:

```
<properties>
    <jakarta-activation.version>2.0.1</jakarta-activation.version>
</properties>
```