# JavaMailSenderImpl got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource with java 17

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, java-17

Spring version: 5.3.10

I upgraded the project to use java 17, the source code can compile but I got the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource` when trying to send the email with `JavaMailSenderImpl` and `MimeMessageHelper`.

The code worked fine with java 8.

I have checked the class DataSource (in jakarta.mail version 1.6.7) and see that it was compiled with java 5.
Seems like it can't work with java 17 for now, can anyone confirm this? and how can I overcome the problem?

Tried to add dependency on jakarta.mail version 1.6.7 as recommendation from Spring (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.10/reference/html/integration.html#mail).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.7</version>
</dependency>
```

My class is very simple, like this:

```
@Service
Class Sender {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender;

    public void createAndSendEmail(Event event) throws MessagingException {
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(javaMailSender.createMimeMessage(), true);
        // config helper from event
        javaMailSender.send(emailGenerator.populateMimeMessage(event, helper));
    }
}
```

And the error occurred when javaMailSender.createMimeMessage() was called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/69930012/150978

Comment: I can't use jakarta.mail version 2.x because of Spring 5.3.10 is stick with version 1.6.x
And I have checked the class DataSource in 1.6.7, it was built with java 5, which might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The missing class should be brought as a transitive dependency by your build tool. `"com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:1.6.7"` brings transitively `"com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation"`, see [the POM on Maven Central](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/jakarta.mail/1.6.7). This artifact contains the `DataSource` class.

Please check your build dependencies with `mvn dependency:tree`. I've successfully compiled a project with a [new Spring Boot app generated on Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.7.13&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=mail&name=mail&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.mail&dependencies=mail).

If the dependency is indeed listed, you should check whether it's been corrupted. You can run `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` locally.

Comment: yes, I can see the transitive dependency jakarta.activation in the jakarta.mail, and the source code can compile. But this is the run time error when sending email.
Everything is ok with java 8, but not for java 17.

Comment: please update your question with a code snippet.

Comment: I have updated the code snippet, it is just very simple with JavaMailSenderImpl and MimeMessageHelper

Comment: I've just tested it and it works for me.

Comment: can you share me your testing source